# How to disable <select> if there is a value on column , php

Tags: php

I want to disable "select" if there is a value on column in php,

```
<select name="number[$i]" class="form-control">
    <option>{$userinfo["number"]}</option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>                
</select>
```

assuming that select name='number'(column name) is have a value so the select box would be disable, but if 'number' is null the select box is free to select , how can we do this ? please help :)

Comment: please post this as answer not comment

Answer (score 0):

Just add a ternary operator as an attribute to test,

so if it is NULL, echo disabled, else echo an empty string (like nothing is there)

```
<select name="number[$i]" class="form-control" <?php echo ($userinfo["number"] =='' ? 'disabled' : ''); ?>>
```

Comment: Tidier making the ternary as part of $disable = in the first line, kepping logic and output separate ;-)